# Naemon still sending DOWN notifications for removed host

Tags: nagios, ubuntu-16.04, notification

I shutdown an old web server, and immediately started receiving DOWN notifications from Naemon.

Now I have removed that host entirely from the Naemon config, and restarted the Naemon service. Yet I continue to receive DOWN notifications every hour.

How do I stop these?

The whole Naemon configuration is almost 2000 lines, so much too long to include here; the virtually default naemon.cfg is over 1000 lines itself.

Is there some parameter(s) causing a host to be saved in some cache? I can find the host listed in `/var/lib/naemon/status.dat`

Comment: Please include your naemon configuration.

Comment: @vidarlo Thanks, but I solved the problem with some more Googling. Have answered my own question in case someone else runs into a similar situation with Naemon seemingly retaining old configuration (which it technically was doing because it wasn't actually restarting...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread and post solved the problem for me:

https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=32630&sid=7cd3fc62673fec6539b082de7c1bb7c5&start=10#p136526

There is no "hidden cache" or parameter for it; the config 100% defines which hosts/services are checked.

The problem was that Naemon wasn't shutting down properly for some unknown reason. I had been using `systemctl restart naemon` -- and even `systemctl stop naemon` followed by `systemctl start naemon` across all of our Naemon nodes.

But just now when I checked with `ps -ef | grep naemon` after shutting down Naemon I saw that there were still process running. I killed them with `kill -9 <parent pid>`, and started Naemon again. No more DOWN notifications!